# How to store data from Task<string> to string?

Tags: c#, string, azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to read the txt.gz file which is in a container, for testing. Now it is working without any problem.
But I call this method many times for each scenario.
Is it possible to store the data into a string (or sth), not to read the data each time? Because the execution time is so long.
I want to read and store the data as a string only once. And then I can use this string multiple times. Is it possible?

```
    public async Task<string> GetTheBlobData(string blobName)
    {
        BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString,containerName);

        var blockBlob = container.GetBlobClient($"{blobName}");

        // Get the blob file as text
        using (var gzStream = await blockBlob.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(gzStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(decompressionStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                  return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: as in `string myStringIWillReUse = await GetTheBlobData("..");` ? Surely you know how to do this already, so can you expand on your question a bit?

Comment: To clear things up: Your _actual_ problem is: You want to keep the string in order to use it throughout several unit tests instead of pulling it in each test. Is that correct?

Comment: storing a string is as simple as awaiting the method and... storing the string; if you mean something more complex like momeoization - it is a *bit* tricky because the `blobName` parameter could be different each time, so: you'd need to think about the number of possible values of `blobName` - i.e. is it sufficient to just reuse things without ever letting go?

Comment: Fildor, yes the actual problem is exactly what you said.

Comment: Marc Gravell, there will be a daily blob, with another created method, I can get the name of the daily blob. My problem, I my automated framework, I need the txt blob data so many times. And when I use the "dataStr" each time ((( string dataStr = GetTheBlobData(blobName).Result; ))) , it replays from the beginning, reading the blood, storing into string etc. Or Am I wrong? The txt has 3milion rows, it is a bit tricky to execute the scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're after is *memoization* (meaning: cache the values and return the pre-existing values for known inputs), then you might try something like using a concurrent-dictionary to re-use the existing *tasks* for each in-flight operation (`Task[<T>]` can be awaited any number of times and is robust vs threads, but importantly: do not do this with `ValueTask[<T>]`, which can only be awaited once):

```cs
class MyType
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<string>> _memoized
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<string>>();
    public Task<string> GetTheBlobData(string blobName)
        => _memoized.GetOrAdd(blobName,
        static (blob, obj) => obj.GetTheBlobDataImpl(blob), this);
    private async Task<string> GetTheBlobDataImpl(string blobName)
    {
        // your existing code...
    }
}
```

Note, however, that this will memoize failure as well as success.

(if you're not using C# 9, just remove the `static` keyword; I'm using that to make sure we don't have any capture scope allocation issues)

Comment: Thank you Marc, memoization is a new topic for me. How can I get a string from your code, sorry for this basic question?

Comment: @EmreKara exactly the same as you would have before: `var blob = await GetTheBlobData("foo");` - just that now it only executes the fetch code once per unique `blobName`